# Connectedness and Continuity

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Suppose $S^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with unit Euclidean norm. That is 
$$S^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n~:~\|x\|=1\}$$
If $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~n>2$, is continuous then prove that there exists $\omega\in S^{n-1}$ such that $f(\omega)=f(-\omega)$.

I think we need to use the connectedness of $S^{n-1}$ for this problem. Any other plausible hints will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem] some clue

Answer (score 2):

Try solving it first for a function from $S^1\to \mathbb R$. Then to prove the general case, show that $S^n$ contains a copy of $S^1$ (for all $n\ge 1$). Again, think of $S^2$ before you jump to higher dimensions. Do you see that $S^2$ contains lots of copies of $S^1$? Do you see then how to prove the result for $f:S^2\to \mathbb R$ from knowing it for functions $f:S^1\to \mathbb R$?

Notice that connectedness alone can't be sufficient for the result. For instance, $\mathbb R$ is connected, but can you think of examples of functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ without $f(x)=f(-x)$?

Comment: what do you mean $S^2$ contain copies of $S^1$. And give some hints, how to show the result for $f:S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: Try to think of $f$ as a $2\pi$ periodic function on $\mathbb R$ and (somehow) use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha isn't the equator a copy of $S^1$ in $S^2$?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Yeah, I have understood that but still couldn't grasp how that helps me to solve the above problem. For $f:S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ its too easy. Can you elaborate the rest of your solution.